# Get first occurrence indices of elements in DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame, df, with a `datetimeindex` that looks like this:

```
                Cluster
Date        
2021-01-28 16:39:00  1
2021-01-28 16:40:00  1
2021-01-28 16:41:00  0
2021-01-28 16:42:00  2
2021-01-28 16:43:00  1
```

How can I get the first occurrence indices of all Cluster elements and get an output like this:

```
Output: [0, 2 , 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.drop_duplicates('Cluster').index
```

Output:

```
Index(['2021-01-28 16:39:00', '2021-01-28 16:41:00', '2021-01-28 16:42:00'], dtype='object', name='Date')
```

Or if you want the row number, reset index:

```
df.reset_index().drop_duplicates('Cluster').index
```

Output:

```
Int64Index([0, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
```